# Erro ao tentar renderizar uma partial view em uma view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma View(cshtml) e nela preciso chamar uma partialView. Essa Partial é uma tabela com os logs daquela Venda, que será visualisado em formato tabular na parte inferior da View. O problema é que quando tento abrir a View(Index) pego esse erro:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SubscriptionCenter.Core.Domain.Logs.LogAlteracao]'.

Como resolvo isso?

Esse é meu html onde "registro" a Partial View

```
<div class="margin-40-b">
    <p>@Html.Partial("_LogAlterarMarkup", Model.CustomerId)</p>
</div>
```

Já fiz assim:

```
<p>@Html.Partial("_LogAlterarMarkup")</p>
```

e assim

```
<p>@Html.Partial("_LogAlterarMarkup", Model.CustomerId)</p>
```

e também assim

```
<p>@Html.Partial("_LogAlterarMarkup", Model.OrderId)</p>
```

**OBS**: A partial view é outra Model(Log)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta está na sua mensagem de erro:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SubscriptionCenter.Core.Domain.Logs.LogAlteracao]'.

Você está passando para a Partial um `Int32` mas nela é esperado um `IEnumerable<LogAlteracao>`, passando o tipo correto provavelmente será renderizado corretamente, se não houver erros na `partial`, claro.

Comment: E como eu faço isso? Essa não é a model da View, como pego essa model e passo?

Comment: @pnet como é esperado a model na _LogAlterarMarkup.cshtml? Se possível poste na pergunta.